Date format changing when saving as CSV file
I have data in table format (not ListObject):

ID | Col2 | Date (dd/mm/yyyy) | ...other columns | C2 (last column)

And this code
Sub exportCSV(path_name As String)
    
    Dim wb As Workbook, newWb As Workbook
    Dim dataSheet As Worksheet
    Dim mailTo As String, mailCC As String, mailBCC As String, mailContent As String
    Dim outlookApp As Object, outlookMail As Object, outlookSign As Object
    Dim newFileName As String
    Dim CRMid As String
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set Admin = wb.Sheets("Administration")
    Set dataSheet = wb.Sheets("CRM template")
    dataSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").ClearAllFilters
    dataSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").RefreshTable
    DoEvents
    CRMid = getLetterOfColumn("Id", "CRM template")
    
    ' Copy the desired range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = dataSheet.Cells(dataSheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row
    Dim lastColumn As String
    lastColumn = getLetterOfColumn("C2", "CRM template")
    
    'retirage
    
    dataSheet.Range(CRMid & "6:" & lastColumn & lastRow).Formula = dataSheet.Range(CRMid & "6:" & lastColumn & "6").Formula
    
    
    'Copy
    dataSheet.Range(CRMid & "5:" & lastColumn & lastRow).Copy
    
    
    Set newWb = Workbooks.Add
    
    With newWb.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues ' Paste values
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats ' Paste formats
        '.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths ' Paste column widths
    End With
    
    ' Name new workbook
    Dim name_no_extension As String
    name_no_extension = Replace(wb.Name, ".xlsm", "")
    newFileName = path_name & "\" & "TRACKER_" & name_no_extension & ".csv"
    
     ' Save File as CSV UTF-8
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    newWb.SaveAs Filename:=newFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSVUTF8
    newWb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

end sub

When using the function I do get data in CSV format, but the problem is the Date column format in now m/d/yyyy instead of dd/mm/yy
I found similar question that suggested using local:=True while saving file, but the problem when i use that i no longer get a file in csv format, i just get a normal table format. That parameter breaks the csv format in other words, and the csv have to be UTF-8 encoded.
Am in France and my laptop setting for region are correct and have ; seperation and dd/mm/yyyy format.
The CSV file columns are seperated with , and not ;

What is a normal table format ? local:=True works for me.

Not CSV, just data in table format, meaning multiple columns instead of one column that i should have in a CSV file

Do you mean the file has commas separating the values and you want semi-colons ? Open the file with notepad.

no my problem is jut about the Date column, i just tried to give all the info

Does local:=True not give the correct date format ?, it does for me.

that's whats weird, when i use local the csv file created is no longer in csv format, and when i remove only local:=True i get correct format for the file, but not the Date

@Maoane what file format do you get if you use the local parameter? What is wrong?

The most reliable way of creating CSV from Excel is to write the file "manually", by two nested loops. It rarely does require more lines of code than your current solution. It may be a little bit tricky for getting UTF8 output, but you may look here

@Maoane Have you checked the contents of the CSV file with a text editor (eg Notepad or Notepad++) and seen the same? Sometimes this sort of issue is due to the program you are using to check the CSV file, and not the CSV file itself.

Better to use FileSystemObject it gives more control.
Something like
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim csvFile As String
Dim fso As Object
Dim stream As Object
Dim line As String

Set rng = "your range"

' Define the CSV file path
csvFile = "you file"

' Create FileSystemObject and TextStream
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set stream = fso.CreateTextFile(csvFile, True, False)

' Loop through each row in the range
For Each cell In rng.Rows
    line = ""
    For Each cell In cell.Cells
        line = line & cell.Value & ","
    Next cell
    ' Remove the trailing comma
    line = Left(line, Len(line) - 1)
    stream.WriteLine line
Next cell

' Close the TextStream
stream.Close


Compile error : For control variable already in use

Please change the variable name of inner "for each" loop from "cell" to "cellNext" or as per your preference.
